# Dotnet Core run the bat file in console application

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

I am trying to run bat file from my dotnet core application. Its creating the new process but  and waiting for execution to finish but in reality nothing is happening bat file code is not taking effect.
I have kept bat file in project itself and made it always copy so it will be available for execution

Below is my code

```
 Process processer = new Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = @$"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}\abc\mybatfilename.bat {parameter}";
        startInfo.RedirectStandardError = false
        processer.StartInfo = startInfo;
        processer.Start();
        processer.WaitForExit();
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Could the batch file be doing something that only affects the current process? If it sets an environment variable or changes the directory or something, for instance, the change wouldn’t persist. Could the batch file be relying on something that isn’t present in the spawned process?

Comment: Show what the bat file does.

Comment: Why do you need to run the bat file? You are already creating a CMD process, why not just supply it with arguments? Eg. ``cmd /c cd bar && mkdir foo``. Also maybe post the code of the batch file, since it's likely that the issue is with the file itself and not the C# code which works/spawns the process.

Comment: @padeso Bat file is changing directory to point third party application and run it with some parameters